# Insert numbers into a single field MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, integer

I'm trying to insert diferent numebers (like "10 11 12") into a MySQL field (the numbers come from PHP), but when I do the query, the field only gets the first number.

For example, I do:

```
UPDATE profile SET subcategory = '10 11 12' WHERE userId = 1 LIMIT 1
```

And the DB just registers '10'.

Any way to do it?

Comment: This sounds like an XY-problem. Please tell us about X. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Learn about joins.  You need another table.

Comment: How large is the field? Looks like could be truncating?

Comment: if subcategory is type of int then it is converted to int so the first proper int which is 10 will be put to table

Comment: increase your field length.

Comment: Probably bad db design.

Comment: I don't know what's more sad, people suggesting that field length is changed or field type. It's obvious this is bad database design. If you have multiple subcategories assigned to a single profile, you insert more rows, each row being subcategory_id linked to the same profile_id/user_id or whatever. Those are the basics. As for going the bad route - that's personal choice. And the guys suggesting increasing field length/type just proves that reputation on this website means nothing when total newbies can obtain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happen because you're updating a number, probably an integer, so mysql do the job just for the first number.

If you do this:

```
UPDATE profile SET subcategory = 10 WHERE userId = 1 LIMIT 1
UPDATE profile SET subcategory = 11 WHERE userId = 1 LIMIT 1
UPDATE profile SET subcategory = 12 WHERE userId = 1 LIMIT 1
```

You'll just update the category with the third value (12).

I suggest you a user belonging to multiple subcategories so you'll have to create another table. Eg: a table called subcategories with at least two fields: userId and subcategoryId. And then you could do something like this:

```
DELETE FROM subcategories WHERE userId=1
INSERT INTO subcategories (userId, subcategory) VALUES (1,10)
INSERT INTO subcategories (userId, subcategory) VALUES (1,11)
INSERT INTO subcategories (userId, subcategory) VALUES (1,12)
```

The first line (delete) is used just to update the user's subcategories, first you delete all older subcategories for the user and then you insert the new ones. In PHP you could use a foreach() to automatize the insertion of multiple values.

You could also have a non unique userId in the table profiles with an entry per user subcategory but it will complicate things.

I hope it could help you

Answer (score 0):

From your problem I guess that the type of your subcategory is integer. What happens when you put string? It is converted. The converter convert it to first proper integer which is 10 space after 10 is considered as string.

What can solve your problem?

1. Chance db structure and depend on relations.
2. (bad idea) change the type to varchar for example and then insert will be done(DONT DO IT)
3. Do multiple updates(it really depends on db structure)

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

If you are just trying to store a small number of numbers then using the php join and split functions to take a list of numbers and convert to and from a string and store that in a VARCHAR.

A better way to solve the problem would be to understand the layout of your data. Try having a table that links profiles to subcategories. Two columns, one for the profile ID and one for the Subcategory ID. You might find having a search for database normalisation informative.

This presentation looks relatively informative: http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/MDBS01CD/page_26.htm